# Blazor EventCallbacks not correctly "bubbling up"

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a strange problem with binding to events.

In a component, I have this:

```cs
[Parameter]
public int Foo { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<int> FooChanged { get; set; }
```

In the outer component:

```cs
<FooComponent @bind-Foo="_foo" />
Foo is: @_foo

@code {
  private int _foo;
}
```

If I do a `await FooChanged.InvokeAsync(42)` in the child component, `_foo` in the outer component is correctly updated and I get `Foo is: 42`.

However, if I bind the `Foo` in the child component to another component using the binding mechanism, like, e.g., a `RadzenNumeric`, this change is not reflected unless I explicitly supply an appropriate event.

That means:

```cs
<RadzenNumeric @bind-Value="Foo" />
```

does not work, the `FooChanged` event never fires.

I have to use:

```cs
<RadzenNumeric Value="Foo"
               ValueChanged="(async (int i) => await FooChanged.InvokeAsync(i))" />
```

This seems rather clunky, coming from WPF with its binding through `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Is this the desired way or is there anything I am missing?

To my understanding, `@bind-...` should automatically set up the correct events, firing the `...Changed` event appropriately, or not?

Comment: I asked myself the same question the other day. I found only this paragraph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#eventcallback

Comment: And apparently this is how it can be done:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#binding-with-component-parameters

Comment: Exactly this is how I am currently doing it - instead of `@bind-...` I am specifying `Value` and `ValueChanged` explicitly. I can't believe it has to be done in this roundabout and clunky way...

Comment: Well, docs don't lie... But this not most convenient, isn't it...